# Set signal value using .NET from Visual studio in CANoe

Tags: c#, .net, vector, canoe, automotive

how can i change signal value in CANoe from C# in Visual Studio? I don't want to make a test module and run it from CANoe, i just want to run from Visual Studio and signal value to be changed. I get this error when i'm trying to set a signal value:

**Vector.CANoe.Runtime.Internal.DBTypeNotFoundException: 'The type *SignalName* could not be found in the configuration.'**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using Vector.PanelControlPlugin;
using NetworkDB;
using Vector.CANoe.Runtime;
using Vector.CANoe.Runtime.Internal;
using Vector.CANoe.Runtime.ValueEntitiesInternal;
using Vector.PostCompiler;
using Vector.CANoe.Sockets;
 
using Vector.CANoe.VTS;
 
using Vector.CANoe.VTSInternal;
using Vector.Diagnostics;
using NetworkDB;
 
 
namespace Demo
{
    public class Class1// : IPanelControlPluginLibrary
    {
        [OnChange(typeof(NetworkDB.PAAK_WELCOME_LIGHTS))]
        public static void OnSignalLockState()
        {
            double value = 1;
            NetworkDB.PAAK_WELCOME_LIGHTS.Instance.GetValue();
            
        }
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            OnSignalLockState();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code. It is impossible to guess what your setup looks like, which APIs you are using, etc.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nqW2CYeW - this is my code, i'm using references from CANoe 15 @M.Spiller

Comment: Add the code to the question. Not as a link into the comments...
Apart from that, The Vector.CANoe.Runtime assembly can only be used from within CANoe, i.e. when running as a node or a snippet. If you want to change signals _from outside_ you have to use the COM interface.

Comment: Now the code is added into the question, so i must use the COM interface? Is any documentation for that?

Comment: You can find it in CANoe's documentation at _Technical References_ -> _COM Interface_.

Comment: Ok, and i can run the script independent from visual studio to change the signal value while the measurement is on right?

Comment: Visual Studio is an IDE. The compiler generates an EXE which can be run from wherever you want.

Comment: Yeah i know that, so to be clear i want to change the signal value without a test module from CANoe or any running from it, and you tell me i can do that with COM interface?

Comment: That is the purpose of the COM interface. CANoe comes with an application node called _CANalyzer/CANoe as a COM Server_ which also covers this use case.

Comment: Okee, thank you a lot. I'm trying to do this now

Comment: @M.Spiller Hello mate, thank you a lot for your help, i'm here for another question to you, do you know how can i change a value of a signal from a message that is send using a CAPL function. So i've already did a CAPL function and send a message, but i want to change de value of the signal (from that message), the problem is CANoe said to me that "no signal driver is available". Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please create a new question on stackoverflow. As usual provide all details needed. That way others can contribute and others above all others can find the answer in case they have similar questions. Do not ask completely unrelated questions in comments.

Comment: I've created already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assemblies `Vector.CANoe.Runtime` can only be used in .NET code which is run *within* CANoe, i.e. in Nodes, Tests, Snippets, etc.

If you want to interact with CANoe *from outside* you have to use the COM-Interface of CANoe.